# How to split a column with comma separated values and store in array in PySpark's Dataframe? As given below

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column that contains comma separated values. The number of values 
that the column contains is fixed (say 4). Example:

```
+------------------------+
|col1                    |
+------------------------+
|1,val1, val4            |
|2,val1                  |
|3,val1, val2, val3      |
|4,val1, val2, val3, val4|
+------------------------+
```

Now I want it to be split into 2 columns like below

```
+----+------------------------+
|col1|col2                    |
+----+------------------------+
|   1|[val1, val4]            |
|   2|[val1]                  |
|   3|[val1, val2, val3]      |
|   4|[val1, val2, val3, val4]|
+----+------------------------+
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this using [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) and [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, slice

array_len = 4
df.withColumn("ar", split(col("col1"), ",")) \
  .select(
     col("ar")[0].alias("col1"), 
     slice(col("ar"), 2, array_len).alias("col2")
  )

# +----+---------------------------+
# |col1|col2                       |
# +----+---------------------------+
# |1   |[val1,  val4]              |
# |2   |[val1]                     |
# |3   |[val1,  val2,  val3]       |
# |4   |[val1,  val2,  val3,  val4]|
# +----+---------------------------+
```

First we split and store the array into `ar`, next we use select to retrieve the first item of the array with `col("ar")[0]` and the rest of the array with `slice(col("ar"), 2, array_len)` which will return all the items except the first one.

Comment: What does `2` in slice indicates?

Comment: we keep the items 2-4, the slice function starts counting from 1

Comment: Okay understood but why do you defined `array_len` manually? Is there any way to specify range like we do in pandas `iloc[10:]` which means tenth row and onwards.

Comment: no, slice just accepts integers @Sid_K (not even Column i.e `size(col("ar"))`)

Comment: Cool. Thanks Alex!